# TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I had included the jQuery_1.8.2 js file and then included this code but iam getting the error..

> TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function [Break On This Error]
>
> data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6,
>   4.8]

i just created a div with id container ..where i went wrong..any order 
of placing js files wrong..?How to resolve this issue..?

```
 <script>
        buildHighCharts();
        function buildHighCharts(){
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'line',
                        marginRight: 130,
                        marginBottom: 25
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                        x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '°C'
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: -10,
                        y: 100,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Tokyo',
                        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
                    },  {
                        name: 'London',
                        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
                    }]
                });
            }
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts1/highcharts-2.3.5.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts1/modules/exporting-2.3.5.js"></script>
```

Comment: where are you calling `buildHighCharts()`?

Comment: just updated the script..with function calling..

Comment: This isn't likely creating the issue you're seeing - but you really shouldn't call the function before you declare it.

Comment: Just got the same issue !! Did you fix it ?

Comment: @Fred FLECHE..I Just removed second js file..exporting-2.3.5.js and thats fixed the issue..

Comment: @TroyAlford There is nothing wrong with calling a function before it's declared. It's a feature of the language.

Answer (score 7):

> any order of placing js files wrong..?

Yes. Your highcharts setup code needs to come **after** the script tags that loads the highcharts library.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts1/highcharts-2.3.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts1/modules/exporting-2.3.5.js"></script>
<script>
    function buildHighCharts(){ ... }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your respose Matt..even though iam getting the problem..that why i used the word 'order'

Comment: just updated code check once..

Comment: What you are missing is really simple: 1.<JQUERY LIBS COMES FIRST>  2.<HIGHCHARTS LIBRARY FOLLOWS>  otherwise you will have highcharts being loaded first before jquery which causes the above issue. Jquery should be loaded first in the page before highcharts

Answer (score 3):

You are using highcharts before you added it to the page. The includes need to come before!

Comment: thanks for quick reply epascarello..i had already tried like that but iam not able to resolve it..

Comment: just updated the error check once..

Comment: So you moved the tags in front of the script tag with buildHighCharts(). did you clear the cahce to make sure you had the right code. Are you sure the highcharts js is there on the page?

Comment: yep js is there and cleared the cache but not able to clear the issue..

Comment: What you are missing is really simple: make sure :- 1.<JQUERY LIBS COMES FIRST> 2.<HIGHCHARTS LIBRARY FOLLOWS> .Oherwise you will have highcharts being loaded first before jquery which causes the above issue. Jquery should be loaded first in the page before highcharts.doing so solves the above issue.

Comment: My problem just got solved by just placing jQuery at the top. Stupid people using jquery for the core library. Thanks FOndieki